# Number of ways of partitioning $a+b$ objects into $k $ partitions such that every partition has at least one object

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

Given 'a' identical objects of one kind and 'b' identical objects of other kind. Also, given 'k' indistinguishable buckets. In how many ways can one put the '(a+b)' objects into the 'k' buckets such that every bucket has atleast a single object?

As an example, let's suppose we have 3 As and 2 Bs and we need to partition them into 2 buckets. (a=3, b=2, k=2).
The possible combinations are:

1. A  | AABB
2. AA | ABB
3. AAA | BB
4. AAAB | B
5. AAB | AB

So, there exist 5 such partitions.

Comment: Does the ordering withing the bucket matter (i.e. order in which the objects are put in the bucket)?

Comment: No, the ordering within the buckets doesn't matter.

Comment: I just saw your example. You say the buckets are different (distinguishable), but your example does not seem to make it so.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't meant different as in distinguishable. The buckets are indistinguishable.

Answer (score 1):

It would be surprising if a closed form could be given for this number, since setting $b=0$ would give the number of partitions of $a$ into $k$ parts, for which no closed form is known. But we can readily write down a generating function by analogy with the partition number generating function: The desired number is the coefficient of $x^ay^bz^k$ in

$$\prod_{{\scriptstyle l,m=0}\atop{\scriptstyle l+m\ne 0}}^\infty\frac1{1-x^ly^mz}\;.$$

Answer (score 0):

Arrange in the a + b objects in a line. One can get $\frac{(a + b)!}{a! b!}$ such arrangements. Then, by [the bars and stars theorems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29), we know that we can partition the arrangement of a+b objects into k buckets in ${a+b-1\choose{k-1}}$ possible ways. Therefore, in total,$$\frac{(a + b)!}{a! b!}{a+b-1\choose{k-1}}$$

Comment: Won't this double count? $a| a bb$ and $a|b a b$ will be counted differently? (Assuming a bucket is a "multiset").

Comment: @Aryabhata Good point! I guess I will have to sit on it a bit more.